# Assign variables from subquery stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle 11.2.0 stored procedure that returns a few output parameters.  The results for the query are being with a refcursor that is being populated from a complex subquery.  I need to return the count of the records from the subquery as a NUMBER output parameter.  I'm having trouble trying to assign the count to a variable inside of the subquery.  Can someone let know if this is possible in Oracle or If there is another way of doing this. I only need to return the data and the count of the data records from the stored procedure.  I'm not sure how to assign and return the count because the query results are being returned from the subquery select statement.  An example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
p_results           OUT sys_refcursor,
p_count             OUT NUMBER
OPEN p_results 
FOR 
  WITH Output1 AS
    (
    SELECT * from table1
    ),
output2 AS
    (
    SELECT * from table2 a
    left outer join Output1 b
    on a.id = b.id
     )
    Select * from output2
    p_count := select count(id) from output2   --how can I return parameters for results and count using subquery
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want.  Oracle has no idea how many rows a cursor will return until the last row is fetched.  And since a cursor is a forward-only structure, if your goal is to return the cursor to the calling application, you can't fetch from it in your code.

You could repeat the query and do this in two steps

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
  INTO p_count
  FROM (<<your query>>);

OPEN p_results
 FOR <<your query>>;
```

That has the obvious downside that you're going to run the query, count all the results, and then re-run the query a second time which is relatively inefficient.  It has the less obvious downside that the `count` may not match the number of rows returned by the cursor because some other session may commit between the time that your initial `SELECT` statement starts and the time that your cursor is opened, thus changing the set of rows that will be returned.

You could also add a computed `count` to every row of your result, i.e.

```
OPEN p_results
 FOR ...
     Select o2.*, count(*) over () cnt 
       from output2 o2
```

That would eliminate the potential for the two queries to return a different number of rows.  It would, however, make the query potentially much more costly because Oracle would need to materialize the result set before the client could start fetching from it.  It's probably still more efficient than running the same query twice unless the additional numeric value that is repeated on every row creates performance issues by increasing the amount of data that needs to be transmitted across the network or buffered by the client.

Generally, I'd be pretty dubious about any design that returns both a count and a set of results to the calling application.  The calling application is going to need code to fetch from the cursor anyway.  If it has that code, it is perfectly suited to count the number of rows that it actually fetches and to then act on that computed result.  Your procedure ought to just return the `sys_refcursor` and leave the counting to the client.

Comment: would there be any way to store the refcursor in a table variables to get the count and still return p_results from the stored procedure?

Comment: @user3397437 - You could, I suppose, declare an object type that matches the projection of your `select` statement (changing your code so that you're not doing `select *` any longer), declare a SQL collection of that object type, `bulk collect` the data from your query into an instance of that collection type, and then return both the count and a `sys_refcursor` that is the result of querying that collection.  That is potentially very memory intensive depending on the size and quantity of data that is involved but it's possible.  You'd probably be better off with a global temp table though.